# Multiplication operator by $x$ on $L^2(0,1)$ is isomorphic to its square

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

The following is Exercise II.8.7 from J. B. Conway's *A Course in Functional Analysis*.

> Let $A:L^2(0,1)\to L^2(0,1)$ be defined by $(Af)(x)=xf(x)$ for $f$ in $L^2(0,1)$ and $x$ in $(0,1)$. Show that $A\cong A^2$.

Here $A\cong A^2$ means there is an unitary isomorphism $U:L^2(0,1)\to L^2(0,1)$ such that $UAU^{-1}=A^2$. I guess I should construct an explicit isomorphism, because $A$ is not compact, and the author has not proved any structure theorem for non-compact operators yet. However, I don't know how I can find such an isomorphism. I understand that $L^2(0,1)$ has Hilbert basis $e^{2\pi inx}$, and I computed the matrix of $A$ with respect to this basis, but I can't see how $A\cong A^2$.

Any hints will be appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $V\in B(L^2(0,1))$ be given by
$$
Vf\,(x)=\frac{f(\sqrt x)}{\sqrt2\,x^{1/4}}.
$$
This map is invertible: if
$$
Wg\,(x)=\sqrt{2x}\,g(x^2)
$$
then $VW=WV=I$, so $V$ is invertible. Also,
$$\tag1
\|Vf\|^2=\int_0^1\frac{|f(\sqrt x)|^2}{2\,x^{1/2}}\,dx=\int_0^1|f(u)|^2\,du=\|f\|^2. 
$$
So $V$ is a unitary. And,
$$
VA^2f\,(x)=V(x^2f)\,(x)=\frac{x\,f(\sqrt x)}{\sqrt2\,x^{1/4}}=AVf\,(x). 
$$
This gives us $VA^2=AV$, and then $VA^2V^*=A$.

Comment: Thanks! May I ask how did you find such a map?

Comment: The unitary couldn't be multiplication, because it would commute. Next thing to try was a change of variable, since unitaries are isometric. Natural change of variables were  $x\longmapsto x^2$ and $x\longmapsto \sqrt x $, but they need to preserve the equality  $(1) $, so I included the (square root of the) change of variable.